# Selfoptimization ffmpeg script

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, powershell-4.0

I'd like to split mp3 Files at a specific range by silence.
To do that I have the following script, but don't know how to stop and restart the search function:

```
 $minDuraton = 180
 $maxDuraton = 480
 $paramDB = -42
 $w_paramDB = $paramDB


 $silparam = [string]$w_paramDB+"dB:d=0.2"

C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -v warning -i "C:\mp3\test.mp3" -af silencedetect=$silparam,ametadata=mode=print:file=-:key=lavfi.silence_start -vn -sn  -f s16le  -y D:\Mailbox\09_Tools\PS_Scripte\mp3\Tmp_silents_part.txt|
%{ if ($_ -match "start"){
    $i++
    $text,$time = $_ -split "="
    $p_Duration = $time - $StartPart
    if($p_Duration -gt ($maxDuraton +10)){
    # Stop ffmepg and restart with new parameter

     ##### -please help- #####

    # editing Parameter
    $w_paramDB = [INT]($w_paramDB * 1,10)

        }
    elseif($p_Duration -ge $minDuraton ){
        $null = $PartArr.Add($time)
        $StartPart = $time
        } 
    }
}

$PartArr
$i
$segments = ($PartArr) -join ","   #PartArr | Join-String -Separator ','

$segmentsC:

C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\mp3\test.mp3" -f segment -segment_times $segments "C:\mp3\output_silc_%03d.mp3"
```

Comment: It's unclear what, specifically, you need help with. Also, you'll stand a better chance of getting help if you add sample input data and describe the expected output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay. I found that FFmpeg just pipe, when it is ready with work. The Input is a long mp3 and I'd like to have multiple outputfiles a splitet at differend silent points.

Answer (score 0):

THE ACTUAL SCRIPT:

```
function getMp3Leange($path)
    {
    $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
    $folder = Split-Path $path
    $file = Split-Path $path -Leaf
    $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($folder)
    $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($file)
    $hoch = 2
    [int]$mp3Lange = 0
    $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27) -split ":"|ForEach-Object{$mp3Lange= $mp3Lange + ([int]$_*[math]::pow(60,$hoch));$hoch--}
    return $mp3Lange
    }




function ffmpeg_caller{
    param($datei_FullName=[STRING]"",
          $i_minDuraton  = [int] 0,
          $i_maxDuraton  = [int] ($i_minDuraton*1.2)            
          )
     
     #Start paramter
     $PartArr = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
     $SD_PARAMS ="-55dB:d=0.3"
     $paramDB = -20
     $w_paramDB = $paramDB
     $repeat_search = $true

     while($repeat_search){
     # working parameter
     $StartPart = 0
     #$w_paramDB
     $silparam = [string]$w_paramDB+"dB:d=0.2"
     $repeat_search = $false
        C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -v warning -i $datei_FullName -af silencedetect=$silparam,ametadata=mode=print:file=-:key=lavfi.silence_start -vn -sn  -f s16le  -y D:\Mailbox\09_Tools\PS_Scripte\mp3\Tmp_silents_part.txt|
        %{ if ($_ -match "start" -and -not $repeat_search){
            $text,$time = $_ -split "="
            $p_Duration = $time - $StartPart
            if($p_Duration -ge $i_minDuraton ){
            Write-Host "Gefundene Zeit $p_Duration vergleich mit Schwelle $i_maxDuraton."
                if($p_Duration -gt ($i_maxDuraton +10)){
                    # Stop ffmepg and restart with new parameter
                    $repeat_search = $true
                    # editing Parameter
                    $w_paramDB = [INT]($w_paramDB * 0.90)
                    Write-Host "New threthold $w_paramDB!"
                }else{
                    Write-Host "duration ok."
                    $null = $PartArr.Add($time)
                    $StartPart = $time
                } # end max dura
            }# end min 
        }# end pipe
      }
    }#end while
return $PartArr
}
#>


$t_mp3 = "C:\inTest.mp3" #1h input MP3
getMp3Leange -path $t_mp3


$o_PartArr = ffmpeg_caller -i_minDuraton 180 -datei_FullName $t_mp3  #getSilenceList 

$o_path = '"'+(Split-Path $t_mp3) +"\Track03%d.mp3"+ '"'#(Split-Path $t_mp3 -Leaf).Substring(0,(Split-Path $t_mp3 -Leaf).Length -4)+"%03d.mp3"+'"'
$o_path
$segments = ($o_PartArr) -join ","   #PartArr | Join-String -Separator ','

$segments




C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i $t_mp3 -f segment -segment_times $segments $o_path
```

The Output Error is:

```
"C:\mp3\Track03%d.mp3"
183.278,366.713,547.452,729.559,913.986,1094.58,1278.08,1462.63,1645.03,1829.3,2009.97,2191.22,2372.46,2555.37,2738.9,2919.16,3099.74,3282.06,3463
.24,3646.01,3829.36,4012.69,4194,4375.28,4557,4737.06,4924.8,182.717,366.651,547.198,729.555,913.762,1094.51,1276.73,1457.69,1638.29,1825.49,2006.
11,2186.91,2371.55,2552.35,2734.93,2917.19,3097.53,3280.21,3460.72,3642.22,3824.97,4006.01,4187.38,4370.03,4556.99,4737.05,4924.71,181.699,362.249
,543.036,723.354,906.665,1088.82,1269.36,1449.85,1632.4,1824.88,2006.11,2186.91,2371.43,2552.34,2734.54,2916.13,3096.24,3276.56,3460.02,3641.2,382
2.72,4003.58,4184.35,4366.73,4547.16,4727.22,4909.2,5117.49,5300.67,5481.75,5666.94
C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe : ffmpeg version 2023-11-09-git-acf63d5350-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the 
FFmpeg developers
In C:\mp3\Split by silence.ps1:77 Zeichen:1
+ C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i $t_mp3 -f segment -se ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ffmpeg version ...mpeg developers:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --pkg-config=pkgconf --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect 
--enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib 
--enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 
--enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e 
--enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl 
--enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi 
--enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid 
--enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan 
--enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb 
--enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc 
--enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b 
--enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      58. 32.100 / 58. 32.100
  libavcodec     60. 33.100 / 60. 33.100
  libavformat    60. 17.100 / 60. 17.100
  libavdevice    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavfilter     9. 13.100 /  9. 13.100
  libswscale      7.  6.100 /  7.  6.100
  libswresample   4. 13.100 /  4. 13.100
  libpostproc    57.  4.100 / 57.  4.100
Input #0, mp3, from 'C:\inTest.mp3':
  Metadata:
    ...
   date            : 2018
  Duration: 01:36:22.13, start: 0.025056, bitrate: 160 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : LAME3.99r
    Side data:
      replaygain: track gain - -4.900000, track peak - unknown, album gain - unknown, album peak - unknown, 
  Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2550x2550 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> png (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 000002785e492000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
    Last message repeated 3 times
[segment @ 000002785e438540] Specified time 182.716995 is smaller than the last time 4924.799805
[out#0/segment @ 000002785e48a340] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error while filtering: Invalid argument
[out#0/segment @ 000002785e48a340] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
Conversion failed!
```

-> Don't know where the error is...